# Find if a specific choice is in a Data Frame R

Tags: r

I have a `Data Frame` object which contains a list of possible choices. For example, an analogy of this would be:

```
FirstName, SurName, Subject, Grade
Brian, Smith, History, 75
Jenny, Jackson, English, 60
```

How would I...

1) Check to see if a certain pupil-subject combination is in my Data Frame

2) And for those who are there, extract their grade (And potentially other relevant fields)

?

Thanks so much

The only solutions I've found so far include appending the values onto the end of the Data Frame and trying to see if it is unique or not? This seems a crude and ridiculous hack?

Comment: If i understand right, you simply need to merge  for exaple a=merge(a,b,by.x=c("FirstName","SurName","Subject"), by.y=c("FirstName","SurName","Subject"), all.x=T)

Comment: Perhaps you want to subset the data? Take a look at `?subset` and `?"[.data.frame"`

Comment: Wow, these seem unnecessarily complex for the problem. Thanks for the poiner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
result <- data[data$FirstName == "Brian" & data$Subject == "History", c("Grade") ]
```

Answer (score 2):

learn data subset (extraction) using `base` R.

To subset any data frame by its rows and column you use `[ ]`

Let `df` be your data frame.

```
  FirstName  SurName  Subject Grade
1     Brian    Smith  History    75
2     Jenny  Jackson  English    60
3       Tom  Brandon  Physics    50
```

You can subset it by its rows and columns using

```
df[rows,columns]
```

Here `rows` and `column` can be :

**1) Index (Number/Name)**

Which means subset that give me that particular row and column like

```
df[2,3]
```

this will return second row and third column

```
[1]  English
```

or

```
df[2,"Grade"]
```

returns

```
[1] 60
```

**2) Range (Indices/List of Names)**

Which means subset that give me these rows and columns like

```
df[1:2,2,drop=F]
```

Here `drop=F` to avoid flattening of result and output like a data.frame. It will give you this

```
   SurName
1    Smith
2  Jackson
```

Range also supports `all` by leaving either rows or columns empty like

```
df[,3,drop=F]
```

this will return `all` rows for `third column`

```
   Subject
1  History
2  English
3  Physics
```

or

```
df[1:2,c("Grade","Subject")]

  Grade  Subject
1    75  History
2    60  English
```

**3) Logical**

Which means you want to subset using a logical condition.

```
df[df$FirstName=="Brian",]
```

meaning give me `rows` where `FirstName` is `Brian` and `all` columns for it.

```
  FirstName SurName  Subject Grade
1     Brian   Smith  History    75
```

or

```
df[df$FirstName=="Brian",1:3]
```

give me rows where `FirstName` is `Brian` and give me only 1 to 3 columns.

or create complex logicals

```
df[df$FirstName=="Brian" & df$SurName==" Smith",1:3]
```

output

```
  FirstName SurName  Subject
1     Brian   Smith  History
```

or complex logical and extract column by name

```
df[df$FirstName=="Brian" & df$SurName==" Smith","Grade",drop=F]

  Grade
1    75
```

or complex logical and extract multiple columns by name

```
df[df$FirstName=="Brian" & df$SurName==" Smith",c("Grade","Subject")]

  Grade  Subject
1    75  History
```

to use this in a function do

```
myfunc<-function(input_var1,input_var2,input_var3) 
{ 
    df[df$FirstName==input_var1 & df$SurName==input_var2 & df$Subject==input_var3,"Grade",drop=F]
}
```

run it like this

```
myfunc("Tom","Brandon","Physics")
```

Comment: Thanks. I had most of that down already, but it was the latter most bit that I was trying to get to - how to construct a check based on multiple conditions. In my case I want to match 3 conditions and return multiple outputs for the find.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I've tried implementing this, and I'm getting the error: `Error in df$VARNAME : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

When using a function call: 

`valid<-optsdf[df$VAR1==input_variable & df$VAR2==input_variable2 & df$VAR3==input_variable3,1]`

Comment: what is `optsdf` here. you can subset a `df` using its rows and column only. it should be `valid<-df[df$VAR1==input_variable & df$VAR2==input_variable2 & df$VAR3==input_variable3,1]`

Comment: optsdf is my data frame that contains all the valid selections. It is the same as your df object above, with a different label. As far as I can see, what you have there is what I have and I dont know why it isnt working.

Comment: then you should be doing this 
 valid<-optsdf[optsdf$VAR1==input_variable & optsdf$VAR2==input_variable2 & optsdf$VAR3==input_variable3,1]

Comment: Hey. I fixed the problem - you're right, I meant to use optsdf instead of df. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Try `subset`:

```
con <- textConnection("FirstName,SurName,Subject,Grade\nBrian,Smith,History,75\nJenny,Jackson,English,60")
dat <- read.csv(con, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
subset(dat, FirstName=="Brian" & SurName=="Smith" & Subject=="History", Grade)
```

Maybe `aggregate` can be helpful, too. The following code gives the mean of the grades for all pupil/subject combinations:

```
dat <- transform(dat, FullName=paste(FirstName, SurName), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aggregate(Grade ~ FullName+Subject, data=dat, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Aggregate. My example above was a massive simplification of what I'm trying to do and I suspect probably not helpful in my exact case use. What I have is effectively a Data Frame of all available options to the user + a key maps for labels into useful numbers, I just want to check if a user supplied option is within the possible ones or not.

Comment: I have my data frame which contains all possible options, and a bunch of extra information about them. The analogy above would be that, I want to see if a pupil (Brian Smith) did a subject (History). If so, I wish to retrieve the extra information (in this case simplified) which are then variables I will need to use later